# How to intersect tables in R

Tags: r

I have some file ("intersect.text.table") in format

```
  textid  rate1  rate2  rate3
     foo    200    201    200
     bar   none    203    203
 crowbar    201    200   none
kung-foo    200    201    202
```

Also I have a file ("intersect.text.table") with a list of some `textid`s

```
textid
foor
bar
foo
```

So, I want to get intersection table with file list of `textid`s. In this model case it would be:

```
  textid  rate1  rate2  rate3
     foo    200    201    200
     bar   none    203    203
```

How it can be done with R?

---

I tried an advice from comment. However, I have got a wrong answer. There is a code:

```
> x = read.table("intersect.text.table", head=TRUE)
> y = read.table("intersect.text.list", head=TRUE)

> x[y$textid %in% x$textid, ]
   textid rate1 rate2 rate3
2     bar  none   203   203
3 crowbar   201   200  none
```

Comment: How about `x[y$textid %in% x$textid, ]`?

Comment: Try `x[x$textid %in% y$textid, ]`instead. Also this isn't a `data.table` question, shouldn't it be untagged?

Answer (score 2):

Using data.table,

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df1, key='textid')[df2, nomatch=0]
#    textid rate1 rate2 rate3
#1:    bar  none   203   203
#2:    foo   200   201   200
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(textid = c("bar", "crowbar", "foo", "kung-foo"
), rate1 = c("none", "201", "200", "200"), rate2 = c(203L, 200L, 
201L, 201L), rate3 = c("203", "none", "200", "202")), .Names = c("textid", 
"rate1", "rate2", "rate3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))


df2 <- structure(list(textid = c("foor", "bar", "foo")),
.Names = "textid", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

@Roman Luštrik's suggestion in the comments was slightly wrong. Since you're subsetting values from the data frame `x`, you need to find the values of `x` in `y`, and not the other way around:

```
x[x$textid %in% y$textid, ]
```